# tree(1) colours not properly interpeted by watch(1) even with --color option

Tags: colors, watch, tree

I am using a simple combination of commands to "monitor" a bit of my filesystem change: watch and tree.
Except I want colours and can't get it.

Here's what I thought should work: `watch --color 'tree -C'` which kind of works since it gives me some colours, but not in the same way as `tree -C` by itself.

Here's some screencaps:
[watch --color 'tree -C'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IrtU.png) output, with some colours applying
[watch 'tree -C'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QedOG.png) output, showing that tree does indeed send all escape codes
[tree -C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uQKC.png) output, expected result

Culprit might also be in my env variables, but if I `watch 'echo $LS_COLORS'`, my conf is there.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that **`watch`** and **`tree`** use different information for getting the colors:

- The **`watch`** program interprets standard (ECMA-48) escape sequences for specifying video attributes.  That means **8** colors, plus bold, blink, underline, reverse and italics.  It uses (n)curses to display the information, making the result depend on the terminal database
- The **`tree`** program mimics GNU **`ls`**, using the **`LS_COLORS`** environment variable.  That uses the **`TERM`** environment variable (which curses and most other terminal applications use to identify an entry in the terminal database) to select a set of customized escape sequences, which do not necessarily have any relationship to the terminal database's descriptions.

With some work, you could make those match, e.g., by generating a suitable **`LS_COLORS`** for  a given terminal entry.  Apparently no one has done that.  And since the contents of **`LS_COLORS`** incomplete (covering only a small fraction of a terminal description: no function keys, no cursor movement, no generality), there is no point in generating a terminal entry from **`LS_COLORS`**.

If **`tree`** uses 256 colors, **`watch`** may not understand those codes (a recent change addresses a part of this issue for procps **`top`** but has not been adapted for **`watch`** — wait a while).  **`watch`** uses (n)curses to manage the screen, which makes it necessary (for **`watch`**) to translate escape-codes into curses-calls.

Further reading:

- [How do I get color with VT100?](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color)
- [Applications miscited as library users](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#not_library_users)
- [The Tree Command for Linux Homepage](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/)
- [procps (watch development)](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps)